# How to use dictionary imported from EDGAR using their API

Tags: python, dictionary, finance, edgar

I am very new to python so this is likely a stupid simple question. I have imported financial statements from EDGAR-Online using their API and it imports as a dictionary. I have read all I could find on dictionaries and understand the key:value relationship. However, the data comes in the following format:

"{'result': {'totalrows': 4, 'rows': [{'rownum': 1, 'values': [{'field': 'basicepsnetincome', 'value': 0.77}, {'field': 'costofrevenue', 'value': 432592000.0}, {'field': 'dilutedepsnetincome', 'value': 0.76}, {'field': 'ebit', 'value': 28455000.0}, {'field': 'grossprofit', 'value': 186708000.0}, {'field': 'incomebeforeextraordinaryitems', 'value': 22622000.0}, {'field': 'incomebeforetaxes', 'value': 31356000.0}, {'field': 'incometaxes', 'value': 8734000.0}, {'field': 'netincome', 'value': 22622000.0},..."

The 'field' and 'value' are the keys from my limited understanding of dictionaries but that would mean their is duplicates of the same key. Regardless, I am trying to figure out how to pull out values from the above data such as 'ebit' which has a value of '28455000.0'. I would think it should be {'ebit' : 28455000.0} then 'ebit' is the key that would reference 28455000.0. Any help on how to pull data points such as ebit from the data set above that can be referenced to a variable and then subsequently be used in calculations would be greatly appreciated.

Used requests.get

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests

IS = requests.get(https://datafied.api.edgar-online.com/v1/corefinancials? 
primarysymbols=MSFT&appkey={APPKEY}).json()
```

### print(IS)

returns data listed above.

Possible helpful links to the EDGAR API documentation
- https://developer.edgar-online.com/docs/v1#nav8

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the url and the code that generates this data?

Comment: Yes, just added code, uses a simple requests.get(). Also attached a link to the EDGAR API documentation, which also shows how the data comes out in a little better format than my question. @JackFleeting

Comment: if dtype of IS is `dict` then you can do pd.DataFrame(IS)

Answer (score 0):

The returned json from this site has a strange structure, but with a little effort you can get to it:

```
import json
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse
IS = """[your json snippet above, converted into valid json]"""
target = json.loads(IS)

fields = []
values = []
jsonpath_expr = parse('result[*].rows[*].values')
for match in jsonpath_expr.find(target):
    for i in match.value:
        for index, element in enumerate(i.values()):
            if index % 2 == 0:
                fields.append(element)
            else:
                values.append(element)
for f, v in zip(fields,values):
    print(f,' - ', v)
```

Output:

```
basicepsnetincome  -  0.77
costofrevenue  -  432592000.0
dilutedepsnetincome  -  0.76
ebit  -  28455000.0
grossprofit  -  186708000.0
incomebeforeextraordinaryitems  -  22622000.0
incomebeforetaxes  -  31356000.0
incometaxes  -  8734000.0
netincome  -  22622000.0
```